# Chained delete with Illuminate in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this code:

```
$pdb->table('settings')->where('slug', '=', 'paypalFee')->delete();
$pdb->table('settings')->where('slug', '=', 'paypalDiscount')->delete();
$pdb->table('settings')->where('slug', '=', 'pay-sbx')->delete();
$pdb->table('settings')->where('slug', '=', 'pay-application-id-sbx')->delete();
```

For multiple deletions using Illuminate, it's possible to chain that code in order to execute in one line or maybe using some Query Builder shortcut in Laravel4? I'm new to Laravel and Illuminate (coming from Symfony2 + Doctrine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a `whereIn` would do the trick here.

```
$fieldsToDelete = array('paypalFee', 'paypalDiscount', 'pay-sbx', 'pay-application-id-sbx');
$pdb->table('settings')->whereIn('slug', $fieldsToDelete)->delete();
```

Taken from the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/queries